# Measurement integral from archive table at 15 minute intervals for hours between hour 1 and hour 2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a archive DB and for argument sake a table thats called MeasurementArchive with 3 columns Name,Time_Stamp, and measurement. Measurements are recorded every 15 minutes for some names and 60 minutes for others. I am wanting to write a query that (where it applies) will take the measurements that are recorded at 15 minute intervals and return a avg for the hour that those measurements were recorded. I am just not sure how to go about this..

Ex.

```
Select * From MeasurementArchve    
Where time_stamp between '01-jan-2016' and '05-jan-2016'
```

Table Sample

```
Name,        Time_stamp,             Measurement

x1,      01-01-2016 00:15:00,           2

x1,      01-01-2016 00:30:00,           4

x1,      01-01-2016 00:45:00,           5

x1,      01-01-2016 01:00:00,           3

x2,  ETC.......
```

I want it to take the measurements from each hour within the date range and return a avg value for it.. Hope you guys can help!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the AVG function. You just have to group by the hour so you can get the average. But since you also want multiple days I am unsure if you want the average for each hour or each hour of each day. I did this to get the average of each hour for each day. If you want the average across all days just change the select and group by to "DATEPART(hour, time_stamp)".

```
create table MeasurementArchive
( 
    name char(2)
    , time_stamp datetime
    , Measurement int
)

insert MeasurementArchive(name, time_stamp, Measurement) values
('x1', '01-01-2016 00:15:00', 2),
('x1', '01-01-2016 00:30:00', 4),
('x1', '01-01-2016 00:45:00', 5),
('x1', '01-01-2016 01:00:00', 3)

select name
    , AvgMeasurement = AVG(Measurement * 1.0) --Need to multiple the int by 1.0 to force decimal places
    , MeasurementHour = dateadd(hour, DATEPART(hour, time_stamp), convert(datetime, (convert(date, time_stamp))))
from MeasurementArchive
group by name
    , dateadd(hour, DATEPART(hour, time_stamp), convert(datetime, (convert(date, time_stamp))))
```

Comment: Thanks That Worked!!